# How to convert string to a PictureBox in C#

Tags: c#, string, list, picturebox

I have an array of type PictureBox. I want to fill it the List of string and then covert it to the Barcode. But I am uncle to convert the string to the PictureBox. Is there any step I can do to make them compatible?

```
System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[] PictureBoxArray = new PictureBox[3];
List<string> serial = new List<string>;

public void ConvertToBarCode()
{
   BarcodeLib.TYPE barcodetype1 = BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE39;
   BarcodeLib.Barcode bar1 = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
   bar1.IncludeLabel = true;
   PictureBoxArray[0] = serial[0]; // Want to Convert String to PictureBox
   PictureBoxArray[0].Image = bar1.Encode(barcodetype1, SerialNumberList[0]);
}
```

I have filles the serial List with the string now just want the conversion.

Comment: What do you expect the line to do, even if it compiled? what do you expect to happen when you convert a string to a picturebox?

Comment: you can look may question it could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244595/convert-a-string-to-a-bitmap-in-c-sharp

Comment: I first have to fill the PictureBox array then change its Image property.

Comment: we know but how look the sting?

Comment: My string looks like this "S1101243" now I use the Encode method to take the string and pass it to the Image property of the PictureBox like this PictureBoxArray[0].Image = bar1.Encode(barcodetype1, S1101243); But before that I have to pass value to the PictureBox[0] otherwise it will give the NullReferenceException.. And my actual problem is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228198/how-to-print-the-barcode-format-in-c-sharp

Comment: ok your logic have an mistake you cant create an pic with a such littet sting but te string is the identyfyer to find the picture ore let it calculate see the other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

you want like this.. right?? see this is the representaion of the this string "S1253551" in 3of9 and plain text and finally as image right??

```
public Image stringToImage(string inputString)
{ 
    string text = inputString.Trim();

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);

    //Set the font style of output image
    Font font = new Font("Free 3 of 9", 25, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    Font font2 = new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    int width = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Width;
    int height = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Height;

    int height2 = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font2).Height;

    bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, new Size(width, height+height2));
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);



    //Specify the background color of the image
    graphics.Clear(Color.Cyan);
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;



    //Specify the text, font, Text Color, X position and Y position of the image
    graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
    graphics.DrawString(text, font2, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, height);

    graphics.Flush();
    graphics.Dispose();

    //if you want to save the image  uncomment the below line.
    //bmp.Save(@"d:\myimage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    return bmp;
}
```

## Remember you must have installed "free 3 of 9" font.

you pass the string "S1253551" and it generate the barcode and add the plain text at bottom and finally return it as image.

Its working code i have tried at my end. Enjoy. :)

Download the working code from here [Download](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bxxluya0NKB2di1nR2Q3aEtzRDg)

Comment: Obviously the OP already has a barcode library. Your solution might work, but is far away from the original code, does not use the barcode library any more and was exchanged by a new library (which is the font in this case).

Comment: @ThomasW. has posted this same question 2-3 place and I have asked him. He want me to use this free 3 of 9 font.  its the explanation how can we create an image from two string. 

if you want to use another lib its upto you. you just need to modify 2-3 line in above code. MIND IT.

Comment: Deepak: Thank you very much for this class. I'm using it to display the barcode representation of part ID numbers and I was having trouble getting the image into a PictureBox using font 39. Incidentally, I was already using the "Free 3 of 9" download for other projects and it works perfectly; I don't see any issues with using it as others suggested. BTW, I suggest you not use ImageLayout.Stretch on the BackgroundImageLayout property and instead go with 'Center' and a larger font size. Stretching creates problems with scanners trying to read a possibly blurred image. Thanks again. --Tim